# Angular 4 rewrite the asset url

Tags: angular

My application root path in F5 level is www.example.com/test/. In my angular application my assets are declared in relative path as src="../assets/icon.jpg". When the application lands at index.html, the assets are not loading as the assets trigger the call to server as www.example.com/assets/icon.jpg.

I have tried with  inside index.html page, this is loading the assets without relative path as expected but the one with relative path doesn't load as expected

I expect the network trigger as www.example.com/test/assets/icon.jpg when src="../assets/icon.jpg" but its being fired as www.example.com/assets/icon.jpg

Comment: maybe try with `./assets/....`?

Comment: I can try that. But we have tons of places to make that change if it works as expected. Any other single place change you can suggest?

Comment: Considering that your `index.html` is most likely at the same folder level than your `assets` folder, the current relative path is incorrect. So solving this by replacing the relative path with the correct one should be the one and only option, independent of how many places this needs to be applied (which can be easily done by some regex search + replace). I guess a different approach would be to proxy the request and redirect it to the correct path, but that seems unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks Jota. I think that's the only possibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding src="./assets/icon.jpg" instead of src="../assets/icon.jpg" fixed my issue. Now everything works fine.

Comment: I was wondering how on the earth someone might have faced this issue. But anyway I looked up here and I got my problem solved. Saved days for me.